How to approach photonics related research works?
I am a student in sophomore year in a college pursuing electrical and electronics engineering. My college offers chance to major in any of the 3 sectors of this department which are:
1)Electronics and photonics
2)Communication and signal processing
3)Power.
I was fascinated on knowing applications of photonics and wanted to study more on this especially on bio-photonics. Moreover I'm bit interested in learning ML. I have already started ML from coursera and know basic neural networks as well. Although it is kind of stereotypical in our place that ML is mostly required in signal processing. But I was looking forward to any topic under which I could merge both ML and photonics. Is there any such topic?
Also I would like to know about a constructive pathway to learn photonics. I'm not much familiar with quantum mechanics either. What could be the course of action in this case so that I would be able to study about photonics and might involve in research works on photonics?
Thank you.

First and foremost, talk to your advisor.  Second, try to get an internship at a company that employs electro-optical engineers.
You don't need to know much about quantum mechanics to use semiconductor photonics devices effectively -- it's mostly classical optics between the device and the rest of the world, electronics once you get onto the device, and then it's only quantum-mechanics on the device.
Electro-optical engineers are in short supply right now, and probably will be for the rest of the decade.  I'd recommend that you look at what such people do and see if it overlaps with your interests.  It'll be heavily math and physics based, with a need for a wide-based knowledge of both physics and electronics.  It'll be hard, jobs will be few and you'll need to move to them when they open up.  However, as long as EO engineers are in short supply you'll be essential and that'll translate into good pay and job security.

A general pathway could be:

Learn electronics and electromagnetism.
Learn fundamental optics, both ray- and wave-optics as well as optics applications such as waveguides and lasers.
Learn physics of semiconductors and semiconductor-based devices, general solid-state physics.
Some photonic effects, such as Purcell effect, may require some familiarity with quantum mechanics.
Yes, you need to be also comfortable with applying ML algorithms (classical and neural-network-based ones) to various problems.
At some point, you have to complete a project showcasing the knowledge of aspects of the above fields. An easier approach is to find a theoretical problem and solve it with ML. A more difficult one will be to find an experimental problem
Here, you might want to consider projects involving Raspberry Pi or Arduino. The goal is to gain some experience and to enrich a CV.
Networking may be very useful here, perhaps, it is possible to connect with somebody who would facilitate the involvement with photonics and ML. There are quite a bit of research groups out there.

Remarks: In the word "Photonics", there is the reference to "electronics", implying that instead of electrons, photons (particles of light) are used for communication. Nowadays, a popular theme is communication using entangled photons / quantum light, so that, again, some familiarity with quantum mechanics could be beneficial.
